# Squid Proxy process not running

Tags: centos, proxy, services, squid, pid

### Hey community,

some days ago my squid crashed. I'm running **squid 2.6 STABLE21** on CentOS.
The output of the "show squid status" command is just

> squid dead but pid file exists

starting the service displayed an "OK" but trying to stop the squid failed.
The weird thing is, that the squid service is not listed in the "Task-Manager"

So I deleted the /var/run/squid.pid file and tried to restart the service, but I got the following message after executing the command:

> squid: ERROR: Could not send signal 0 to process 3618: (3) No such process

Even restarting the system after that changed nothing.

Also I found some interesting stuff in the /var/log/squid/cache.log

> 2013/08/20 07:57:43| /var/spool/squid/swap.state: (30) Read-only file system
> FATAL: storeAufsDirOpenSwapLog: Failed to open swap log.
> Squid Cache (Version 2.6.STABLE21): Terminated abnormally

I didn't change anything recently. Why is that a Read-only file system now?
How do i change the filesystem to read and write access?

I really hope these error messages make sense to someone of you.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Rob

Comment: One can only guess why the swap state is readonly.  It could be a permissions problem (ie the SQUID user only has read permissions to the parent directory), or it is a separate partition which is corrupted and needs to be fsck'd.

Comment: I just checked that with ls -la. The squid only got read permissions!